# How can I select all subelements of a tag by position?

Tags: python, xml, xpath

I have a xml file which looks like that:

```
<?xml version= "1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<File>
    <Field>
        <Name>CTX_LOG_SYS</Name>
        <ClearName></ClearName>
        <RawValue>000000000000000000000000</RawValue>
        <Array>
            <Name>TX</Name>
            <Row number="0">
                <Value>0</Value>
            </Row>
            <Row number="1">
                <Value>0</Value>
            </Row>
            <Row number="2">
                <Value>0</Value>
            </Row>
        </Array>
    </Field>
    <Field>
        <Name>VICK</Name>
        <ClearName></ClearName>
        <RawValue>0000016B00040</RawValue>
        <Array>
        <Name>VC</Name>
            <Row number="0">
                <Value>33</Value>
            </Row>
            <Row number="1">
                <Value>244</Value>
            </Row>
            <Row number="2">
                <Value>0</Value>
            </Row>
            <Row number="3">
                <Value>363</Value>
            </Row>
            <Row number="4">
                <Value>44</Value>
            </Row>
            <Row number="5">
                <Value>0</Value>
            </Row>
            <Row number="6">
                <Value>3</Value>
            </Row>
            <Row number="7">
                <Value>26</Value>
            </Row>
            <Row number="8">
                <Value>0</Value>
            </Row>
        </Array>
    </Field>    
</File>
```

And i want to extract all the values of the 2nd Array which are `33, 244, 0, 363, 44, 0, 3, 26, 0`.

I can select all content of `Value` tag, but I can't slelect only the value of 2th one by position.

This is my code:

```
for vick in root.findall('./Field/Array[1]//'):
    val = vick.find('Value')
    if val is not None:
        print val.tag, val.attrib, val.text
```

And i get this result:

```
Value {} 0
Value {} 0
Value {} 0
Value {} 33
Value {} 244
Value {} 0
Value {} 363
Value {} 44
Value {} 0
Value {} 3
Value {} 26
Value {} 0
```

Can someone help please?
Thanks!

I am working on a file in which these tags repeate Ntime like this:

```
<?xml version= "1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<File>
    <Param>
        <Field>
            <Name>thydr</Name>
            <ClearName></ClearName>
            <RawValue>000000000000000000000000</RawValue>
            <Array>
            </Array>
        </Field>
        <Field>
            <Name>VICK</Name>
            <ClearName></ClearName>
            <RawValue>000001040</RawValue>
            <Array>
            </Array>
        </Field>
    </Param>
    <Param>
        <Field>
            <Name>thrss</Name>
            <ClearName></ClearName>
            <RawValue>000000000000000000000000</RawValue>
            <Array>
            </Array>
        </Field>
        <Field>
            <Name>VICK</Name>
            <ClearName></ClearName>
            <RawValue>0000016B00040</RawValue>
            <Array>
            </Array>
        </Field>
    </Param>
    <Param>
        <Field>
            <Name>ghytd</Name>
            <ClearName></ClearName>
            <RawValue>000000000000000000000000</RawValue>
            <Array>
            </Array>
        </Field>
        <Field>
            <Name>VICK</Name>
            <ClearName></ClearName>
            <RawValue>000000040</RawValue>
            <Array>
            </Array>
        </Field>
    </Param>
</File>
```

And for each `<Param>` tag i want to take the value of the 2nd `<Array>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this XPath:

```
/File/Field[2]/Array//Row/Value/text()
```

It selects all values of the second array. Or omit the `/text()` at the end to get only the `Value` nodes.
Output is:

```
3324403634403260
```

Use a separator as desired.

Comment: Thnaks @zx485, I had a large file which looks like the file above. Your code works well in my small file but how can I do that in my large file to loop each `<Param>` and take the value of the 2nd `<Array>`. 
Thanks.

Comment: Use `/File/Param/Field[2]/Array/text()` to get it. Notice that the `Array` values in the example XML are empty.

Comment: If this answer was helpful, please accept it by custom.